# PHP calling MYSQL statement and getting output

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT - Thanks so much to everyone's help. In continuing to learn, I am now working a different statement based on what I learned above but it is giving no result whatsoever. Workbench shows the query statement as good and displays result as "2"

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  $sql = "SELECT SUM(`mattiscool`),booking_date FROM `wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager` WHERE `booking_date` = CURDATE() -1";

$result = mysqli_query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
   echo $row['total'];
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I am trying to call via php an MySQL Statement and have that output the values. Below is what I have tried. Could someone please help enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DAYNAME(wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`booking_date`) as \'weekday\',  \n"

    . "              wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`party_size` as \'Party Size\',\n"

    . "              wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`booking_time` as \'Time\',\n"

    . "              wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`mattiscool` as \'# of Reservations\'\n"

    . "FROM wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager\n"

    . "\n"

    . "WHERE `booking_date` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY  \n"

    . "ORDER BY `Time`  ASC";
?>
```

Comment: You assign a string to variable `$sql` here. That's what you do. Please use your favourite serach engine for something like `php mysql tutorial`.

Comment: Check your query outside of php, in MySQL workbench or another tool, such as dbeaver or DB Visualizer. Does your query return data there?

Comment: Query is good in workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your query and fetch the result [as follows](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT DAYNAME(wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`booking_date`) as \'weekday\',  \n"

    . "              wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`party_size` as \'Party Size\',\n"

    . "              wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`booking_time` as \'Time\',\n"

    . "              wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager.`mattiscool` as \'# of Reservations\'\n"

    . "FROM wp_cbxrbooking_log_manager\n"

    . "\n"

    . "WHERE `booking_date` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY  \n"

    . "ORDER BY `Time`  ASC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so  much. I didnt realize I had to open the connection each time. In learning from the above example and google, I have the following that doesnt seem to be working while incorporating what you were kind enough to share. Any help would be great.

(connection opened via proper syntax)......

$sql= "SELECT SUM(`mattiscool`),booking_date FROM `"table_name"` WHERE `booking_date` = CURDATE()";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
while($row = $result){$row[0]}


 else {
echo "0 results"
}
$conn->close();
?>

Comment: Please update your question if there are further details. Are you trying a different query? Is the problem that now rows are returned?

Comment: updated question. Yes this is a separate statement using the information and help you provided to try and learn.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete, you have to establish a connection to database and then execute the query to get the output. You can find some good examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this remain true when working off the localhost?

Comment: Sure. If you are in localhost you have to estabilish connection to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and probably port 3306. If you are using over internet than you just change the ip and port.